Can you use an RDS proxy just like you're connecting to the database itself?
Can you use an AWS RDS proxy just like you would the database?
So; server, user, password, database
i.e. proxy_endpoint, db_user, password, database
I can see guides for using a certificate. We're not using it for security. It's on an internal network. We're using it as we have too many connections.
It's a bit if a newb question I know.
I tried just swapping the database server to the proxy endpoint but that didn't work.
